# What happened to the rxjs "join" operator?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, reactivex

In the *reactivex.io* docs, there is an operator called join:
http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/join.html

What became of this operator? It looks like maybe this was removed in RxJS 5? What can I do to replace it?

In my Angular/TypeScript app, I get a compiler error when I try to invoke .join() on an Observable.

I have tried to import it manually, but there is no "rxjs/add/observable/join" in the NPM module. Even if I put in a TypeScript module declaration to make the compiler happy, I still get an error at runtime.

Comment: As mentioned in [Migrating from RxJS 4 to 5](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/MIGRATION.md), the `join` operator's status is "No longer implemented". You can use the [Choose an operator](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#choose-an-operator) questionnaire to find the operator that fits your needs.

Comment: The migration page has been updated 5 to 6, here is the original 4 to 5:
https://github.com/jeffbski/rxjs-1/blob/master/MIGRATION.md

Answer (score 0):

If you use the join operator with intervals you can replace it with

```
observableA.timestamp().
      combineLatest(observableB.timestamp(),
      (a, a) => {return {a, b})
.filter(({a, b}) => { return Math.abs(a.timestamp - b.timestamp) < 1000})
```